# Oracle How to Clean+Convert Numeric Datatype Column to Date Datatype

Tags: sql, oracle

I have column name `EOSDT` which Numeric datatype i want to convert it to date datatype but the problem the inserted values in this column could be more than 8 digits or less even !!
And the inserted format could be like `yyyymmdd` or `yyyyddmm`
so, any help to convert only the record with 8 digits only 
and get it with `dd/mm/yyyy` format ?

```
select to_date('EOSDT','yyyymmdd') from cpms;
```

Comment: If you don't even have a fixed data format, this is going to be a headache.  Can you really have more than 8 digits?  What do those extra numbers even mean here?

Comment: it could be non numeric characters

Comment: Then update your question showing the full extent of all possible original date data.

Comment: 20092012. YYYYDDMM? DDMMYYYY? 01021999. DDMMYYYY? MMDDYYYY?